# BB10 + Cordova 3.2 + File transfer download not working

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I'm currently developing a Phonegap App using cordova 3.2 and I'm having problems with File transfer in BB10.

To be more concise I have problems with the download method, I'm doing something like this:

`fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {

        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },

    function(error) {

        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    }

);`

That code is working perfectly for me in Android, iOS and WP8. However its not working in BB10, it returns me code error 2 (FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR).

I have tried several solutions, like this: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/BB10-Phonegap-3-0-0-FileTransfer/td-p/2523851 but not succeeded.

I'm thinking the problem could be with permissions in the config.xml file; has any of you a similar code in its project using cordova and BB10 working? Can you help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any other client server calls? Ajax or so?

Comment: Sure, I'm developing with Sencha touch framework and use it for Ajax calls. They work perfectly for all devices, including BB10. I'm also loading local JSON with no problems. However I need file transfer to obtain images and more from the server and that is not working on BB10

Comment: Ok, just asking, because I had really trouble getting allow="*" to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some test I have found the exact method that fails:

```
window.webkitResolveLocalFileSystemURL(decodedURI + '/', function (entry) {
        success(fileUtils.createEntry(entry));
    }, function (e) {
        fail(e);
    });
```

Is placed in File Plugin, in file resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js inside blackbery10 folder.
The method is always entering failure callback.

Hope it helps.